# PREEMPTIVE_OS_WRITEFILEGATHER wait on database RESTORE with IFI on

Tags: sql-server, restore, sql-server-2014, azure-vm

I have an Azure VM with Windows Server 2012 R2 and SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition. I have enabled IFI (added SQL Server user `NTSERVICE\MSSQLSERVER` to "Perform Volume Maintenance Tasks").

I have tried to restore a 3 GB database with files on C drive (SSD) which took about 40 minutes to complete. Checking restore progress, after about 20 minutes it was at 100% complete.

During the restore, I had `PREEMPTIVE_OS_WRITEFILEGATHER` constantly showing up for my restore.

40 minutes for 3 GB database is too much.

Files being on C drive (not good) and with all the rest of activity that was on C drive - could have this impact my restore that bad taking it to 40 minutes, having in mind this is still a SSD drive?

Is there anything else I could look for in order to find what is causing it to take THAT long?

EDIT:
I have checked the following so far:

1 - checked with `EXEC xp_cmdshell "whoami /priv"` and I get `SeManageVolumePrivilege       Perform volume maintenance tasks          Enabled` - so sql server user does have permissions

2 - restarted sqlservice, just to be sure, after the answers below

3 - checked creating a new database with trace flags `3004,3605` ON and it's only logging ldf zeroing, not MDF - so IFI is ON

Answer (score 4):

wBob is right on the money, you need a service restart.  I wanted to enhance his answer and give a script that will also **verify** that IFI is indeed enabled.

This will determine whether or not you need to kick the service to allow the local policy to take.

```
USE MASTER;

SET NOCOUNT ON

-- *** WARNING: Undocumented commands used in this script !!! *** --
--Exit if a database named DummyTestDB exists
IF DB_ID('DummyTestDB') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    RAISERROR (
            'A database named DummyTestDB already exists, exiting script'
            ,20
            ,1
            )
    WITH LOG
END

--Temptable to hold output from sp_readerrorlog
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SqlLogs') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #SqlLogs
GO

CREATE TABLE #SqlLogs (
    LogDate DATETIME2(0)
    ,ProcessInfo VARCHAR(20)
    ,TEXT VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

--Turn on trace flags 3004 and 3605
DBCC TRACEON (
        3004
        ,3605
        ,- 1
        )
WITH NO_INFOMSGS

--Create a dummy database to see the output in the SQL Server Errorlog
CREATE DATABASE DummyTestDB
GO

--Turn off trace flags 3004 and 3605
DBCC TRACEOFF (
        3004
        ,3605
        ,- 1
        )
WITH NO_INFOMSGS

--Remove the DummyDB
DROP DATABASE DummyTestDB;

--Now go check the output in the SQL Server Error Log File
--This can take a while if you have a large errorlog file
INSERT INTO #SqlLogs (
    LogDate
    ,ProcessInfo
    ,TEXT
    )
EXEC sp_readerrorlog 0
    ,1
    ,'Zeroing'

IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM #SqlLogs
        WHERE TEXT LIKE 'Zeroing completed%'
            AND TEXT LIKE '%DummyTestDB.mdf%'
            AND LogDate > DATEADD(HOUR, - 1, LogDate)
        )
BEGIN
    PRINT 'We do NOT have instant file initialization.'
    PRINT 'Grant the SQL Server services account the ''Perform Volume Maintenance Tasks'' security policy.'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'We have instant file initialization.'
END
```

Comment: Did all this and I only get zeroing for ldf, this tells me IFI is on.

Comment: Nice script but I too have ifi and still lots of PREEMPTIVE_OS_WRITEFILEGATHER

Comment: @solublefish that could be your log file growing (log files don't get IFI and have to zero out) or perhaps your data files are set to grow at very small increments and its happening frequently.

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer Of course that was it; Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3):

Did you restart the service?  Instant file initialisation only takes effect after a SQL Server service restart.

Comment: Yep, first thing after giving permissions to sql server to perform volume maintenance tasks